# Why has my Pokemon GO account been reset?

Tags: pokemon-go

I logged in this morning to my Pokemon GO account, and all of my progress has been reset to zero, and I had to completely restart the game.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This incident can mean one of three things: the server is lagging, you're not on the same account, or your account has been terminated for breaking the game rules.

### Server Lag

---

Niantic's servers are still somewhat overloaded, and could simply be making a mistake. Try again a bit later.

### Wrong Account

---

If you're using multiple accounts, you may have simply signed into one without a Pokemon GO profile attached to it yet. Sign in to the correct account and try again.

### Account Ban

---

If you've ruled out the above two, it's very likely that your account was terminated for [violating the rules and/or the ToS](https://www.nianticlabs.com/terms/pokemongo/en) of Pokemon GO. Niantic has been known to wipe these accounts clean, and force players to restart from zero. Alternatively, [banned accounts may be "shadowbanned,"](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4ry7my/psa_spoofing_gps_locations_will_get_you_banned/) where they're unable to see Pokemon or interact with Stops/Gyms.

Possible reasons for termination may include, but is not limited to:

- Using location spoofers/falsifiers
- Using multiple accounts on one device
- Using the account for mapping services
- Using the same account on multiple devices *at the same time*
- Using accounts commercially (lure patching a specific Pokéstop only)
- Using unofficial/modded game clients
- Using unofficial/modded firmwares (jailbreaks, custom ROMs, roots)
- Using emulation software
- And other ToS violations

If this is the case, there is no way to recover your account -- you must start again. And remember, ***cheating in multiplayer games is wrong!***

Comment: Providing some sources, especially for the account ban, would be helpful.

Comment: @Frank Added link to ToS. If that does not satisfy, I'll try to get more sources for this post.

Comment: It seems a bit of a stretch Niantic would just up and wipe people's accounts for cheating.  That's what I was referring to when I asked for sources.

Comment: @Frank: Ah. It's happened to a few Twitch streamers already. I'll look and see if I can find a screenshot of an e-mail or something to that regard.

Comment: @Frank Looking at a list of SE problems and Niantic's stance on Ingress bans, it seems likely that accounts are reset -- note the number of questions here about this reset happening with one of two accounts on a single device. The number of questions specifying multi accounts or multi devices seems to be too high to be a coincidence...

Comment: When I first opened this I didn't realize it was also answered by you. I got really worried for a moment.